# Getting File as a result while returning Json from MVC action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

[image]
//FeedbackController

```
public class FeedbackController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Feedback/

    public ActionResult Search(string name = "hemant")
    {
        var message = Server.HtmlEncode(name);

        return Json(new { Message = message, Name = "Rajesh" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

//Route Config

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("Feedback", "feedback/{name}",
            new { controller = "Feedback", action = "Search", name = UrlParameter.Optional });


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I was playing around with routing stuff. I am trying to get the response as JSON but m getting a response as JSON file, and not as text on the browser. Heres the image

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json response download in IE(7~10)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943439/json-response-download-in-ie710)

Answer (score 0):

I don't Understand exactly what are you trying to do...
But below will show hemant in json Format...

```
 public ActionResult Search(string name = "hemant")
        {
            var message = Server.HtmlEncode(name);

            return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Janina for the answer ! what i am trying to do is simply return a JSON reponse, which should be printed on the browser. What m doing there is creating anonymus Json Object with two attributes . I simply want to show it as a content.

Comment: as Rahul Menon said, you need have a view to take the values to which you want to convert into json

Answer (score 0):

Ideally when you return a JSON there has to be a handler in the view to collect the result and the display
you can check this 
[MVC4 - Displaying JSON result properties in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929182/mvc4-displaying-json-result-properties-in-view)